# Trying to deploy site - failure to deploy error

Tags: git, github, deployment

I'm trying deploy my site and am getting this error:

```
2:49:12 PM: Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'startbootstrap-grayscale' in .gitmodules
2:49:12 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
2:49:12 PM: failed during stage 'preparing repo': Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'startbootstrap-grayscale' in .gitmodules
```

Everything has been commited and pushed up to my repo and I don't think there is anything missing. Any clues as to what might going wrong?

**EDIT**

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true

[remote "origin"]
  url = https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

**EDIT 2**

```
usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] (--all| [--] <path>...)
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--merge|--rebase] [--[no-]recommend-shallow] [--reference <repository>] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] absorbgitdirs [--] [<path>...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your repository uses a submodule. When you use a submodule, there should be an entry for that path in the `.gitmodules` file in the root of your repository, and there should be an entry for the URL in that file. If you lack the file or the proper URL entry, you won't be able to check out the submodule when you perform a clone because Git doesn't know where the other repository is.

For reference, a `.gitmodules` file should look something like this:

```
[submodule "vim-fugitive"]
        path = vim/bundle/vim-fugitive
        url = https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git
[submodule "ctrlp"]
        path = vim/bundle/ctrlp
        url = https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git
```

The `path` component is the path within your repository and the `url` component is the location to download it from.

See the `git-config(1)` manual page for more details about the submodule configuration options.

Comment: appreciate that, i just found out that that is the issue, problem is, not sure how to fix it

Comment: please take a look at the edit and see what I need to change, it's pointing the url in remote origin

Comment: You're showing us the `.git/config` file. What we need to see is the contents of the `.gitmodules` file in the repository.

Comment: i don't see that file anywhere, is that possible that this folder doesn't have it?

Comment: If you have submodules, you need to have one at the root of your repository. You can add one with `git submodule add -f` if you lack one.

Comment: Would I have to add anything to it? And I'm not able to try it right now but do you think that's all I need to resolve the issue?

Comment: Well, as mentioned, you need to have a git-format config file with a appropriate `path` and `url` options. `git submodule add -f` is probably the easiest way to add it if you're not familiar with how to write one. You should use an HTTPS URL if the repository you're accessing is public. That should be all you need to do to fix this particular problem.

Comment: When you're saying that I should use a HTTPS URL, are you saying that i need to add the github url of the folder/file that I need to to there?

Comment: Alright appreciate it, I'll try it soon and see what happens

Comment: im getting this when i type that `git submodule add -f`

Comment: You have to specify at least two arguments to `git submodule add -f`. Please see the manual page.

Comment: ok, so i dl'ed a bootstrap theme and tried adding the submodule thing and now it's saying that `fatal: No url found for submodule path 'startbootstrap-grayscale' in .gitmodules`

Comment: Can you take a look at my other post regarding this? I took a look at the manual page but still am unsure of what to do

Comment: You should write `git submodule add -f URL PATH-TO-SUBMODULE`.

Comment: so if my github was `github.com/github`, I would do `git submodule add -f github.com/github` Folder`? Folder being the directory that I want to add the submodule too?

Comment: You have to use a full URL and the path to your submodule relative to the repository root. So something like `git submodule add -f https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale.git startbootstrap-grayscale`.

Comment: can you take a look at this because it's a little different from what i have above, I believe the command will be a little different than the one you provided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910066/deployment-failure-adding-submodule-issues-using-netlify

Comment: `'startbootstrap-grayscale' already exists and is not a valid git repo`

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been asked a long time ago. just in case it may help.
Netlify describes in a communíty support post the reason of this error, the bottom line as they say is "If you have a private submodule, you’ll need to grant permissions for our build system to access your private submodule"

Based on the Netlify´s desciption of the solution I did the following:

1. I created a deploy key from the project settings on Netlify and added it to 
   the submodule´s settings under deploy keys.
2. After pushing to github which started the build on Netlify I got the same error as described in the question.
3. I changed `https://github.com/user/repo` to `git@github.com:user/repo` in `.gitmodules`, and I pushed again and the build and the delpoyment worked just fine.

Comment: I copied the public key and put it in gitlab. I still get the same error. I'm using git@ url pattern. I'm not sure what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get back with "heroku logs --tail"?
Im assuming you deleted the app and redeployed?

Comment: im using netlify

Comment: it's in the building phase, it starts to build it and then returns this error