# Deployment Failure - Adding submodule issues - Using Netlify

Tags: github, deployment, git-submodules, netlify

I am trying to deploy my site to Netlify, when I try to trigger deployment, I am getting this error:

```
1:46:02 PM: Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'startbootstrap-grayscale' in .gitmodules
1:46:02 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
1:46:02 PM: failed during stage 'preparing repo': Error checking out submodules: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'startbootstrap-grayscale' in .gitmodules
```

My `Folder` directory is the one I want to deploy and these are the contents within that directory.

```
LICENSE             node_modules
README.md           package-lock.json
css                 package.json
gulpfile.js         scss
img                 startbootstrap-grayscale
index.html          vendor
js
```

As you can see, the error is pointing to the `startbootstrap-grayscale` directory.

Within that `startbootstrap-grayscale` directory, everything you see above is within that same directory. (Not sure what I did there to have that happen). If I `cd` into the 2nd `startbootstrap-grayscale` directory, there is nothing inside of it.

I was told that I need to `git submodule add <my github name>` but am not sure what else to add in order to resolve this issue.

`git submodule add -f` asks for more info:

```
usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] (--all| [--] <path>...)
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--checkout|--merge|--rebase] [--[no-]recommend-shallow] [--reference <repository>] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--su mmary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] absorbgitdirs [--] [<path>...]
```

Any suggestions as to what to add in order to fix this issue? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, I needed to get rid of my `startbootstrap-grayscale` folder by using `rm -r startbootstrap-grayscale` and pushing the changes. I had too many nested folders of the same type for some reason.

Comment: Ah okay. Cool ️

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue in different projects a few times before. My solution was usually to decouple the submodule and move the code into my codebase (or using a managed package for this).

To decouple the module go into your submodule folder, delete the `.git` folder and add the files to your git repository. On the command line I would do it like this:

```
// going into the submodule - might need to tweaked, depending on the exact path
cd startbootstrap-grayscale

// delete the git submodule
rm -rf .git

// going out of the directory
cd ..

// adding everything to git
git add .
```

With these steps (and potentially minor tweaks to the paths) I've been able to resolve this issue for me.

Comment: ok so i did what you wrote and after I did the `git add .`, I tried to commit and push it, but it just says the working tree is all up to date

Comment: im supposed to push everything up to github after right?

Comment: my startbootstrap-grayscale folder can't be click on my github. know what the issue might be there?

Answer (score 0):

Completely nuking my git directory and then starting over with a new git commit worked for me. Not ideal but I was trying to get rid of git submodules and it didn't work. Now my site is live! https://connorleech.info/

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git remote add origin YOUR_URL
git add .
git commit -m 'restart history'
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions on Netlify concerning [submodules](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/repo-permissions-linking/#git-submodules). Specifically I used a Deploy key because the submodule was a private repository on GitHub. The process was quite straight forward.

1. In Netlify go to **Site Configuration > Build & Deploy> Continuous deployment > Deploy key** and **Generate public key**.
2. Copy the generated key.
3. In GitHub go to the repository that you are using as a submodule. Go to **Settings > Deploy keys** and **Add deploy key**.
4. Do another deploy on Netlify.